# Grub error: /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 7: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found

Tags: grub2, sound, soundcard

Yesterday I'd installed new driver for my sound card and today the Sound doesn't work. I'd found an answer for this problem and fixed it in `/etc/default/grub`, but now when I try `sudo update-grub` it comes this error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 7: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
```

This is my grub file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

# MANUELL EINGEFUGT
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash pci=use_crs“

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="splash quiet"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that 
obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD . 
..)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports 
via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter 
to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I add this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash pci=use_crs“
```

And I commented this line out:

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: What was the point of changing: `"quiet splash"` to `"splash quiet"`?

Comment: From "quiet splash" to “quiet splash pci=use_crs“

Comment: Also change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="splash quiet"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` - that entry should normally be empty.

Answer (score 4):

Please look closely at the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash pci=use_crs“
```

You will see the `“` should be `"`, perhaps you copied and pasted it from some where. Please re-write that line and use your keyboard don't copy and paste.
And the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="splash quiet"
```

has its entry repeated in

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=use_crs"
```

Make that line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```